# What is the best way to enrich near real-time data in ElasticSearch with batch data that may come in later?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two types of indices in my elasticsearch. The first contains data that is updated in near-real time. The second is data I can use to enhance the first that is updated nightly. I am new to elasticsearch and I'm wondering if there are any good patterns that easily allows me to update the streaming data with the nightly batches.

I've looked at the enrichment processor, but that appears to enrich at time of index. The enrichment data I have might be there, or might show up that night.

My goal is to create a dashboard that uses the enrichment index to help identify what documents in the streaming data I care about; and eventually add more fields for detailed exploration from there. In SQL terms: "count the number of documents where the ID of the stream document exists in the enrichment data", but that is pretty much a JOIN which I believe I should be avoiding given the large size of both indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enrichment processors can be run at index time **but also after documents have already been indexed** using the [`_update_by_query` endpoint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html).

The idea is this: you index your streaming data in real-time. Once your second data set comes in, you can create a new index to store it, then create an [enrichment index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest-enriching-data.html) out of it and finally update your first data set with the [`enrich` processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/enrich-processor.html).