# update-the-context-of-one-document-based-on-the-context-of-other-document in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

We have two types of documents type A and type B both are connected through an Id field

Type A
{
"id": "abc",
"name": "xyz",
"class": "mno"
}

Type B
{
"id": "abc",
}
I want to update all the Type B documents and I want them to have "name" field from the corresponding Type A document.
So the final Type B document should look like
Type B
{
"id": "abc",
"name": "xyz"
}
Is it possible to do such updates through native elastic update queries?

Comment: is _id(not id, Each document has an _id that uniquely identifies it, which is indexed so that documents can be looked up) same between both indexes?

Comment: hi @jaspreetchahal thanks for the response.
both have different _id and both the document types A and B reside on the same index

Comment: This thread might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66632699/4604579 (hint: use an enrich policy)